# Split a string into multiple columns using the whitespaces

Tags: mysql

I have a data base with around 200 categories, however they are not properly classified.

Take the following as an example:

| prod_id | prod_cat | pc_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 dishwasher detergent | 1 |
| 2 | 102 laundry detergent | 2 |
| 3 | 501 disposable diapers | 5 |
| 4 | 502 non-disposable diapers | 5 |

I cannot group them by the pc_code since they are actually 2 subcategories (at least) per pc_code.

I would like to group them by "detergent" or "diapers" (there are 197 of them), and I cannot, or I would rather not do:

```
    SELECT
        prod_cat 
    FROM
        markets.products
    WHERE
        pc_code = 1
    GROUP BY pc_code
    ORDER BY pc_code;
```

for every one of the 197 categories. Although I know that if I implement a for loop in R for example, I could get a group per category.

However I have thought that it would be *cleaner* to split the **prod_cat** field into:

| prod_id | prod_cat_no | prod_sub_cat | prod_cat | pc_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | dishwasher | detergent | 1 |
| 2 | 102 | laundry | detergent | 2 |
| 3 | 501 | disposable | diapers | 5 |
| 4 | 502 | non-disposable | diapers | 5 |

And group by prod_cat. So I would like to split the column in the middle into three columns using the whitespaces, but I have no idea on how to.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ' ', number), ' ', -1)`. For the first numeric value you may use simple `value + 0`.

Comment: *I would like to group them by "detergent" or "diapers"* `WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(prod_cat, ' ', -1) IN ('detergent', 'diapers')`. *And group by prod_cat* `GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(prod_cat, ' ', -1)`

Answer (score -1):

try this, may help you!

```
   SELECT
            prod_cat 
        FROM
            markets.products
    
    GROUP BY product_cat CONTAINS 'detergent' AND GROUP BY product_cat    CONTAINS 'diapers'
```

Comment: Don't try to invent your own syntax - the server will refuse to understand it.